# Render Error: Property 'Button' doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo, jsx

This is my first React Native project and I'm trying to learn, but I'm prevented from continuing because I keep receiving this error. This is a brand-new project created from the expo cli. As soon as I add the "Button" property I run into this error.

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title='Push Me'/>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I am using the following dependencies:

- "expo": "^49.0.3"
- "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
- "react": "18.2.0",
- "react-native": "0.71.8"

Please let me know if i am missing any important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import the `Button` as well:

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
                                 ^
```

Comment: Hahaha! I feel quite dumb. Thank you for the succinct answer. This fixed it right away. You're the man. Lesson learned.